# Changing states for a custom styled ToggleButton with two distinct Path Markup Syntaxes

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I am a beginner in WPF and have been trying to come up with a custom style template for a `ToggleButton`. I've so far managed to define the paths with bezier curves, but got stuck into the following issue:

- How can I combine the two `Path`s, such that when I hover the `ToggleButton`, the color in **BOTH PATHS** is changed according to the attached image. There need to be two distinct color values, one for the main part and the other for the blue bar on the top. Here is a part of my canvas in XAML:

```
<Canvas Width="180" Height="180" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Stroke="#FFB5BECB" Fill="#FFEDF2F7" Data="F1 M 90,18C 109.882,18 127.882,26.0589 140.912,39.0883L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 90,18 Z"/>
    <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Stroke="#FFB5BECB" Fill="#FFCDD5DE" Data="F1 M 90,18C 109.882,18 127.882,26.0589 140.912,39.0883L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 90,18 Z "/>
    <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Stroke="#FF6F9FFF" Fill="#FF6F9FFF" Data="F1 M 89.9999,5.00005C 113.472,5.00005 134.722,14.514 150.104,29.896L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 89.9999,5.00005 Z "/>
    <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Stroke="#FF13487E" Fill="#FF13487E" Data="F1 M 89.9999,5.00005C 113.472,5.00005 134.722,14.514 150.104,29.896L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 89.9999,5.00005 Z"/>
</Canvas>
```

The following image shows the expected primary and the hover states.

[image: Image showing primary and on hover states.]

Answer (score 0):

You can name your elements by assigning an [`x:Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xname-directive). Then you can refer to them in a [`Trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.trigger?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) that checks the [`IsMouseOver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) property on a parent container, e.g. the `Canvas`.

Since you do not provide your full control template, this one is the part that you posted, adapted to change the `Stroke`s and `Fill`s of the `Path`s on mouse over.

```
<ToggleButton Content="Templated Toggle Button">
   <ToggleButton.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
         <!-- ...here might be a container that you did not provide in your question. -->
         <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas"  Width="180" Height="180" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Path x:Name="TopPart" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Stroke="#FFB5BECB" Fill="#FFCDD5DE" Data="F1 M 90,18C 109.882,18 127.882,26.0589 140.912,39.0883L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 90,18 Z "/>
            <Path x:Name="BottomPart" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Stroke="#FF13487E" Fill="#FF13487E" Data="F1 M 89.9999,5.00005C 113.472,5.00005 134.722,14.514 150.104,29.896L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 89.9999,5.00005 Z"/>
         </Canvas>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="MyCanvas" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter TargetName="TopPart" Property="Stroke" Value="#FFB5BECB"/>
               <Setter TargetName="TopPart" Property="Fill" Value="#FFEDF2F7"/>
               <Setter TargetName="BottomPart" Property="Stroke" Value="#FF6F9FFF"/>
               <Setter TargetName="BottomPart" Property="Fill" Value="#FF6F9FFF"/>
            </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

---

Update for your comment. A control template can consist of several named part and visual states that define the visual appearance and behavior of the control. Some parts may even be required for the control to work correctly. You can find them in the [documentation for styles and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/togglebutton-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) with examples, but beware that those may be incomplete.

In case of the `ToggleButton`, [there are many visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/togglebutton-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#togglebutton-states) e.g. *MouseOver*, *Pressed*, *Checked*, and so on. You can simply define storyboards for each to define the appearance and transitions between states. This approach uses the [`VisualStateManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), which is an alternative to styles and triggers. There are many tutorials out there. Your template could look like below. Add storyboards to states as necessary. An easier way to define visual states than editing XAML code is to use [Blend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-blend-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), where you can edit them conveniently using a GUI Editor. See [Blend 2015: Create Visual States](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32809.blend-2015-create-visual-states.aspx) or similar tutorials for an overview.

```
<ToggleButton Content="Templated Toggle Button">
   <ToggleButton.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
         <!-- ...here might be a container that you did not provide in your question. -->
         <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas"
                 Width="180"
                 Height="180"
                 Canvas.Left="0"
                 Canvas.Top="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
               <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                     <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="TopPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="#FFB5BECB" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="TopPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="#FFEDF2F7" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="BottomPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="#FF6F9FFF" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="BottomPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="#FF6F9FFF" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                     </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                     <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="TopPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="DarkRed" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="TopPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Red" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="BottomPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Blue" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="BottomPart">
                           <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Blue" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                     </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
               </VisualStateGroup>
               <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Checked" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
               </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Path x:Name="TopPart"
                  Stretch="Fill"
                  StrokeLineJoin="Miter"
                  Stroke="#FFB5BECB"
                  Fill="#FFCDD5DE"
                  Data="F1 M 90,18C 109.882,18 127.882,26.0589 140.912,39.0883L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 90,18 Z " />
            <Path x:Name="BottomPart"
                  Stretch="Fill"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  StrokeLineJoin="Miter"
                  Stroke="#FF13487E"
                  Fill="#FF13487E"
                  Data="F1 M 89.9999,5.00005C 113.472,5.00005 134.722,14.514 150.104,29.896L 152.225,27.7746C 136.301,11.8497 114.301,2.00002 90,2.00002L 89.9999,5.00005 Z" />
         </Canvas>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Many thanks for proving a solution for me. I can work it up from here now! @thatguy

Comment: I actually need further states for `IsPressed` and `IsChecked` (Properties for a `ToggleButton`). Unfortunately, they don't work with having `Canvas` as a container because `Canvas`does have other `Template Properties`. Do you have any idea what else I could put as a container for my `paths`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's great! I'll have a look into it asap. Thank you!